# simultaneous calling to multiple client in twilio

Tags: java, twilio

As twilio said about simultaneous dialing that

You can use several and nouns within a verb to dial multiple phone numbers and clients at the same time. The first person to answer the call will be connected to the caller, while the rest of the call attempts are hung up.

[image]

I implement this functionality same as described but when someone dial to my twilio number I pass above twiml response and every client receive Incoming call but when one of all client pick the call by .accept() method ,nothing happens and call continuously ring for all client .

But if only one client is ready to receive call and accept incoming call ,everything works fine.

Please help me ,I am in big trouble .

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here. Unfortunately I was unable to reproduce this problem, but if you are continuing to run into issues please e-mail help@twilio.com so we can dig a bit deeper into your account and figure out what is going on.